# Why are some entries so long and strange on Wikidata?

Tags: wikidata, wikipedia

I wonder why Wikidata includes/filters in [this kind of entries](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q105030571):

> Foundations of Astrophysics Barbara Ryden Bradley M. Peterson. 596 pp. Addison-Wesley, San Francisco, 2009. Price: $137.33 (hardcover). ISBN 978-0-321-59558-4 (Q105030571)

> German Reich and Protectorate of Bohemia and Moravia September 1939–September 1941 (Q104958086)

Do they imply mistakes somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [edit history](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q105030571&action=history) of the first one, that item was created by a bot, implying that the machine-readable source data is odd.

The second one [seems to be](https://www.worldcat.org/title/1164624132) correctly named and is merely a long title of a book.

Comment: The first one is a relatively common format in scholarly databases for the title field of a book review in an academic journal - it does look a bit weird but it's a common enough way of structuring them.